# Android Soft Keyboard hiding EditText when reopened

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, kotlin, android-softkeyboard

I am developing an app that requires screen pinning and a full window so I hide the navigation bar etc.

When the activity opens and the EditText gains focus the Soft Keyboard will become visible and it will shift the EditText above it -- Great, no problems there.

The issue appears when I dismiss the Soft Keyboard and reopen it by clicking on said EditText, the Soft Keyboard will now hide the EditText.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this? I have tried containing the entire layout inside a ScrollView and the issue is still happening.

Window flags being used:

```
 val flags = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)

 window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = flags
 window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

Inside my Manifest I use:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

[image: Initial display of Soft Keyboard]

[image: When Soft keyboard is dismissed and reopened]

SOLVED.

I managed to resolve this by removing the input type from the EditText.

Comment: Try changing the windowSoftInputMode. Read more about it here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I have tried using adjustPan, adjustResize and stateUnchanged. It still works correctly when it's first displayed but anytime after, it covers the EditText.

Comment: Try different combinations, like 
    <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >

Comment: Solved it. Removed the input type from the EditText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by removing the input type from the EditText.

Comment: You save the day